# Restriction in Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How to Restrict to choose the future date in Bootstrap Date picker?

here is the code what i tried

```
    $( 'selecter' ).datepicker( {
        maxDate : new Date(),
        autoclose : true
    } );
```

Comment: try setting the `endDate`.. http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/options.html#enddate

Comment: I tried it but it is not working. can you give me the sample code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to restrict the datepicker to only allow the selection of dates in the future, use the following:

```
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        startDate: new Date()
    });
```

To only allow dates in the past, use this instead:

```
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        endDate: new Date()
    });
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tuG6C/620/

Comment: I tried these code but not working. I am using Bootstrap date picker not the jQuery date picker.

Comment: Hi John, there is no DatePicker included with Bootstrap by default, do you mean this one: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/

Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: Great! That's the one I used in the fiddle. Did you look at that? How exactly is yours "not working"?

Answer (score 1):

I use this on my code :

```
$('.disable-past-date-picker').datepicker({
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    onRender: function(date) {
        return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
    }
});
```